# How can I run a portable Perl with CGI on Windows?

Tags: perl, cgi

I need a portable CGI Perl application.

I don't have admin right on the computer where I will install/run the portable Perl CGI software.

Comment: strawberry perl

Comment: how about portable ACTIVEPERL software? any ideas where i can download it?

Comment: Why are you looking for a portable version of Perl? It'll only run on whatever OS it's been compiled for.

Comment: What does this portable Perl CGI program need to do? Seems weird to ask for a program without specifying its functionality.

Comment: Do you want to just run some CGI-based code as part of developing it, or do you want to _host a server_ on a machine you don't have admin rights on?

Comment: i dont have the admin account on the computer where i would like to install the Portable CGi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to distinguish some thing.

### Perl

This is the language your code is written in. It is required to run your code. perl<sup>1</sup> itself is a program as well, which is written in a different programming language and needs to be compiled for your operating system.

There are portable versions of [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html), which is a pre-compiled version of Perl for Windows. You can just drop that on your computer and run without admin rights.

### CGI

CGI is a technology. Older Perl versions included the [CGI.pm module](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod), but it has recently been removed from the Perl core. That means newer versions do not ship with it by default and you need to install it from the [CPAN](https://metacpan.org/).

CGI as a technology and especially the CGI.pm module are considered to be outdated, and using them in new projects is discouraged. You might find [this talk by Sawyer X](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKOqtRMT85), who is the current Perl release manager, entertaining and instructional.

### Running a CGI program

In order to run a CGI program as a website, you need a web server. Typically one would use Apache 2. There are projects like [XAMPP for Windows](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) that bring a development environment with a prebuilt Apache server, MySQL database server, PHP, Perl and other technologies. There are portable versions of that.

If you don't want to bother with all of that and only want to try CGI programs, you can use the Perl module [App::CGIThis](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-CGIThis/bin/cgi_this)<sup>2</sup>, which turns the current directory you run it in into a web server using the Plack/PSGI technology stack.

```
$ cd projects
$ dir
index.pl

$ cgi_this
```

You can now access your *index.pl* with http://localhost:3000/index.pl.

### You program

The code you want to run, written in Perl. This probably consists of a script that uses the CGI.pm module as well as some other, custom modules.

### Dependencies

Your Perl program might require some things that are not part of the core Perl distribution, like CGI.pm. You will have to install these from CPAN. Your portable Strawberry Perl brings a cpan client that you can use to install stuff.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Perl* is the language, *perl* is the name of the interpreter binary that runs Perl programs, and *PERL* is not related to the Perl programming language. [See explanation here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Name).

<sup>2)</sup> Disclaimer: I am the author of that module.